# Attempt to de-reference a null object error .. when inerting new object with recordtype

Tags: apex, record-type

```
public pageReference OpenNewCustomerAccount() {       
  application.RecordType.Name = 'New Customer Application';       
  application.Client__c = account.Id;
  insert (application);      

  return Page.OAOANewCustomerAccount;
}
```

Its giving me error ... on 
   application.RecordType.Name = 'New Customer Application';

System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: Removed the extra commented code to clean things up!

Answer (score 5):

You can't set a look up field in code using the name, you need to use the ID of the record type instead, which you can get by querying the RecordType object.

```
Id RTID = [select Id from RecordType where SObjectType = 'Account' and Name = 'New Customer Application' limit 1].Id;
application.RecordType = RTID;
```

Another point to add is that you should do this based on the DeveloperName field (called Record Type Name in the RT config as opposed to Label) rather than the regular name, as that allows administrators to update the name of a record type without breaking your code.